# How do I attach a child window/panel to parent window in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

The answer eludes me I have no idea and I've searched everywhere on google.

The problem: I already have both windows built and am NOT coding them programatically... so

[window addChildWindow:window ordered:....] etc doesn't help because I don't know how to create a "name" for my pre fabricated windows in Interface Builder...and I can't find a tutorial on what to bind/link

So Im getting frustrated.

Basically Ive already made a main window and a panel..and want the panel as a child of main.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to define IBOutlets in your application delegate.

```
@interface FFAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow * window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPanel * childPanel;

@end
```

Now connect the IBOutlets to the window objects in your xib file. Now the windows will be created for you by AppKit during application launch.

You still have to implement a line of code to add the panel as a child window of the main window.

```
@implementation FFAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [[self window] addChildWindow:[self childPanel]
                          ordered:NSWindowBelow];
}

@end
```

Comment: I did exactly that, and I'm just wondering, shouldn't the child window move with the main window when the main window is dragged?

Comment: It should. But note that the default behavior includes the ability to separately move the child window.

Comment: So how could I make that happen? Thus far the answers I've been seeing where to get a panel to drag with main window it would simply have to be a child window.

Comment: The child window should move when the parent window is moved. It's not optional as uchuugaka suggested. If it's not doing that, then setting the parent-child relationship failed for some reason. Log the values of `[self window]` and `[self panel]` at the time you tried to set it up.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is....
The application won't call this method, hence any add child messages i send to the window object don't occur..case in point i tried this: Nothing happened.. No Log msg showed up

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
}

Comment: Then you implemented that in a class other than your application delegate. That method is an application delegate method. If something other than the app delegate owns/controls the two windows that you want to make parent and child, then you have to do the `-addChildWindow:...` call in a method of that class that gets called when the two windows are created and set up.

Comment: So problem is solved. applicationDidFinishLaunchin wasn't being invoked because Application instance wasn't connected to AppDelegate.

Everything works now!